# File Change Detection not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular6

My Angular project was created in Angular 5, and has been that version for about 6 months or so.  Yesterday I upgraded to Angular 6 and after fixing all my `rxjs` references and compiling the app to make sure everything was working smoothly, I realized that after saving changes while running `ng serve` as well as `ng test`did not refresh my browser or recognize any changes until I killed my `ng serve` and started it over again.

I can't seem to find any answers anywhere; has anyone else run into this problem and can I provide any part of my project to help find a solution?

EDIT:
I am running on Linux/Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: you should update to 6 with ng update which auto adds rxjs-compat - see https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the problem in your code this happens due to sometime VS code or Operting system and this is faced oftenly in Ubuntu/linux, so in linux running the following command as root will solve the problem,

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

and in case of visual studio code:

```
{
    "files.useExperimentalFileWatcher" : true
}
```

in Code -> Preferences -> Settings

Tested with Visual Studio Code Version 1.26.1 on mac and win

Comment: Although I am using Linux/Ubuntu, running this did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Thank you, that vsCode setting change worked for me!